# Date format string simplification

Tags: c

```
    char* dateFormat(char str[]){
    char temp[11];
    temp[0]=str[0];
    temp[1]=str[1];
    temp[2]='/';
    temp[3]=str[2];
    temp[4]=str[3];
    temp[5]='/';
    temp[6]=str[4];
    temp[7]=str[5];
    temp[8]=str[6];
    temp[9]=str[7];
    temp[10]='\0';

    return temp;
};
```

This function takes date string (format DDMMYYYY) and returns another string with format (DD/MM/YYYY), is there any way to make a shorter version of it.

Comment: `char* dateFormat(char str[]){ return 0; }` Address of non-static local variable is invalid after returning, so returning `NULL` should be enough.

Comment: I think what MikeCAT is saying is you need to define char temp[11] outside of the function.

Comment: Oops, there are extra spaces and lengty argument name. It should be `char*dateFormat(char*s){return 0;}`

Comment: @MikeCAT `return (char *)rand();` will more imitate the actual verison

Comment: @IlanKeshet Or `static char temp[11];` should be used instead. Another choice is allocating it dynamically via `malloc()`.

Comment: right. @MikeCAT

Comment: @MikeCAT better if called provides the buffer. Fewer problems with deallocation.

Comment: `char* dateFormat(char *buff, const char *datestr){`

Comment: If the passed string is modifiable and has enough size for 2 more characters you can start at the end and work down: `str[10] = 0; str[9] = str[7]; str[8] = str[6];` ... etc.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of off the top of my head is:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *format (char *src)
{
    char temp [11] = {src[0], src[1], '/', src[2], src [3], '/', src [4], src [5], src[6], src[7], 0};
    return strdup (temp);
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World %s", format ("12345678"));    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that while surely shorter in number of lines, this goes through `src` two times and is certainly slower.

Comment: I take readability over speed any day of the week - especially on something this simple.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I fail to see how this is more readable, both versions are very much "readable" for me... but I guess it's a subjective matter.

Comment: hmmm, goes through src twice? Not quite right, it copies src to a temporary buffer then copies that buffer to malloc'd memory. Using the library function and chaging the "[11]" to "[]" eliminates potential memory problems as this will work with any size string as long as you terminate it properly (the final zero).

Comment: *"it copies src to a temporary buffer then copies that buffer to malloc'd memory"* - so it means that it goes over the same data twice. Doesn't it? That's what I meant, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: I didn't think of it horizontally even though it's an obvious choice.
Thanks, that helped me and answered my question.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your function is invalid: returning a pointer to a local variable is forbidden in C, and you are doing so by creating a local array and returning its address.

You should either:

1. Dynamically allocate the needed memory:

   ```
   char *dateFormat(char *str) {
       char *res;

       res = malloc(11);
       if (res == NULL)
           return NULL;

       res[0] = str[0];
       res[1] = str[1];
       res[2] = '/';
       res[3] = str[2];
       res[4] = str[3];
       res[5] = '/';
       res[6] = str[4];
       res[7] = str[5];
       res[8] = str[6];
       res[9] = str[7];
       res[10] ='\0';

       return res;
   };
   ```
2. Accept a second argument assuming it was already allocated by the caller with enough space:

   ```
   void dateFormat(char *src, char *dst) {
       dst[0] = src[0];
       dst[1] = src[1];
       dst[2] = '/';
       dst[3] = src[2];
       dst[4] = src[3];
       dst[5] = '/';
       dst[6] = src[4];
       dst[7] = src[5];
       dst[8] = src[6];
       dst[9] = src[7];
       dst[10] ='\0';
   };
   ```

Other than this, there is really not much to do to improve your function. Making it any "shorter" doesn't make much sense, as it would most probably also make it slower.

Any function call or loop with branches will inevitably result in slower code. Just compile with optimizations enabled (e.g. `gcc -O3 ...`) and let the compiler do the magic for you. It will most probably turn those two byte assignments as well as the final four byte assignment into a single move assembly instruction.

Comment: Moreover your proposals are reentrant which is a good thing for multi-threaded applications.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that helped me learn more about C.